# Which Ubuntu flavors show `DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu`?

Tags: derivatives

I'm looking for an Ubuntu 22.04 derivative, which has `DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu`. I would like to be able to use software SDK, which require Ubuntu 22.04, e.g. OneAPI, ROS 2, Gazebo, CUDA, etc. I tried Linux Mint 21, but it has `DISTRIB_ID=Mint`. Do officially supported Ubuntu flavors have `DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu`?

---

I checked Ubuntu Mate and it shows `DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu`.

Comment: All *flavors* of Ubuntu use the package `base-files` which exists in Ubuntu repositories, thus will identify themselves as Ubuntu. Only 3rd party OSes (like Linux Mint) or *remixes* may use 3rd party packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All *flavors* of Ubuntu use the package `base-files` which exists in Ubuntu repositories, thus will identify themselves as Ubuntu.

Only 3rd party OSes (eg.your mentioned Linux Mint) or *remixes* may use 3rd party packages.  [Official *flavors*](https://ubuntu.com/desktop/flavours) cannot.

Comment: Ubuntu *flavors* can decide what they put on their ISOs through *seed* files, but they'll only *grab* packages in official Ubuntu repositories, with the build infrastructure being the same as what builds all Ubuntu images (ie. Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server etc...)  The largest difference is probably the *flavors* use ['universe'](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu), after all we're part of wider Ubuntu community.